# How to display a background image with css/php

Tags: php, html, css, image

This might be easy for some of you but it hasnt worked for me so I will ask it anyway..
I have a header file in php...that has a bookstore name in it...right now I have the name of the bookstore appearing after the image.Well I want the image to be the background of the bookstore name..so obviously I have to use background-image..
I have tried adding background image in my header in css and it's not working and am sure am getting the path right...I have even tried to move the image to default folder where my html is but its not working..obviously am doing something wrong so help me please...
here is my php header file(I have commented out the image in the header so it doesn't show).

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title><?php echo $pageTitle; ?></title>
     <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/book.png">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $description;?>">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>

    <body>
 <header id = 'header'>


 <!--<img src='images/bannercut.jpg' id='banner' alt='Bookstore Banner'>-->
  <h1>Gabby's BookStore</h1>


  </header>
```

Here is my css

```
     header{
background-image: url('bannercut.jpg');
  }
```

Comment: In css try putting full URL of image... Just to confirm. After that you can figure out image location related to css location. Try inspect element where you can edit html code without having to check n change css/php file n reload every time.

Comment: I have tried that it's not working..inspect element makes it easier for me to test though..thanks for that ..I will also try inline styling and see why that works

Comment: your stylesheet should reference `#header` since it's by ID   , if it were a class, then  `.header`

Comment: tried that didnt work either

Comment: You have two errors, your CSS is wrong and your URL is wrong too.
@Johannes has the correct answer you need.

Answer (score 3):

EDITED (typos...)

It's the filepath and the selector:

```
 #header{
     background-image: url('../images/bannercut.jpg');
  }
```

`header` is an `ID`, so it needs the `#` in the selector and if your css file is in a folder named `css`, you first have to go *out* of the folder (with `../`) and then *into*  the `images` folder in your filepath, resulting in `../images/bannercut.jpg`.

Answer (score 0):

Based one what I see. It looks like you didn't write some stuff down correctly. Let me explain: When you give something a id, you just write down `<header id = "header">` remember when you write it that you have to put quotes "" around it not single quotes ''.

Also, when you state an ID in CSS, you have to put a `#` before the ID name. For example:

```
#header {
/* your code here */
}
```

Also. When you stated your background image's link. You have to put quotation marks around it "" not single quotation marks ''. For example:

```
background-image: url("banner cut.jpg");
```

Basically, to fix your code, all you have to do is change the header tag in CSS to

```
  #header{
background-image: url("Funny Background.png");
color: white;
}
```

and then change the HTML header id to

```
 <header id = "header">
```

ALSO. MAKE SURE TO PUT IN CLOSING TAGS!! You forgot to write  at the end of the code.

Good luck :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
header#header {
background: url(bannercut.jpg);
}
```

Or:

```
header#header {
background: url(images/bannercut.jpg);
}
```

you should add the id of it after u specify header and remove the ' from in the url and remove -image from behind background and

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your code

```
<?php
   $background_url = " //Your URL goes here ";
?>

<style>
   header{background: url( <?php echo $background_url ?> );
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should insert style in original file

example:

```
<style>
.header {
    background-image: url(<?php echo $headerImgUrl; ?>);
}
</style>
```